# getText from GUI textfield error in java

Tags: java, swing, textfield, gettext

I am doing a project where I have to convert a fraction into its lowest terms. I am experiencing errors with .getText from a JTextField. I printed their input and the input is being received as the properties rather than as a string. I am having problems with this code:

```
    double userDenominator = Double.parseDouble(userDenominatorInput.getText());
```

this give the variable a value of

```
javax.swing.JTextField[,12,93,166x36,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@c112a58,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],selectionColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],columns=0,columnWidth=0,command=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING]
```

I was wondering if any problems could be caused by me using a GUI form or a key released listener.

Here is the full code separated into two classes:

```
package reducefraction;

public class ReduceFraction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewJFrame form = new NewJFrame();
        form.setVisible(true);
        form.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

}
```

Here is the second class

```
package reducefraction;


public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */
public NewJFrame() {

    initComponents();
    userDenominatorInput.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            userDenominatorInputKeyReleased(evt);
        }
    });

    userNumeratorInput.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            userNumeratorInputKeyReleased(evt);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    userDenominatorInput = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jSeparator2 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    numeratorOutput = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    denominatorOutput = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    userNumeratorInput = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("Reduce Fractions");

    jLabel2.setText("This program will reduce a fraction to its lowest terms");

    userDenominatorInput.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Gabriola", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    userDenominatorInput.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 51));

    numeratorOutput.setEditable(false);
    numeratorOutput.setColumns(10);
    numeratorOutput.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Gabriola", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    numeratorOutput.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 51));

    denominatorOutput.setEditable(false);
    denominatorOutput.setColumns(10);
    denominatorOutput.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Gabriola", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    denominatorOutput.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 51));

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tempus Sans ITC", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setText("=");

    userNumeratorInput.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Gabriola", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    userNumeratorInput.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 51));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(155, 155, 155)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(75, 75, 75)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)))
                    .addGap(0, 82, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(jSeparator1)
                        .addComponent(userDenominatorInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 166, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(userNumeratorInput))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(jSeparator2)
                        .addComponent(denominatorOutput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(numeratorOutput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 31, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(userNumeratorInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(userDenominatorInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(jSeparator2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 14, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(denominatorOutput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(numeratorOutput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(50, 50, 50)))
            .addGap(22, 22, 22))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        
**public void userDenominatorInputKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    double userDenominator = Double.parseDouble(userDenominatorInput.getText());
    double userNumerator = Double.parseDouble(userNumeratorInput.getText());
    calculate(userNumerator, userDenominator);
    }
public void userNumeratorInputKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    double userDenominator = Double.parseDouble(userDenominatorInput.getText());
    double userNumerator = Double.parseDouble(userNumeratorInput.getText());
    calculate(userNumerator, userDenominator);
    }
public void calculate(double userNumerator, double userDenominator) {
        System.out.println(userNumeratorInput);
        double a = userDenominator;
        double b = userNumerator % userDenominator;
        double c;
        do {
            c = a % b;
            a = b;
            b = c;
        } while (a != 0);
        int greatestCommonDenominator = (int) c;
        double numeratorAnswer = userNumerator / greatestCommonDenominator;
        double denominatorAnswer = userDenominator / greatestCommonDenominator;
        numeratorOutput.setText(Double.toString(numeratorAnswer));
        denominatorOutput.setText(Double.toString(denominatorAnswer));
}**

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextField denominatorOutput;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator2;
private javax.swing.JTextField numeratorOutput;
public javax.swing.JTextField userDenominatorInput;
private javax.swing.JTextField userNumeratorInput;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: Don't use `KeyListener`s on text fields, use a `DocumentListener` if you want to do real time updates or rely on the fields `ActionListener` support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MadProgrammer gave me the answer I needed that was causing the output of properties rather than a string. This Problem is solved by doing the .getText method as described here:

*Don't use System.out.println(userNumeratorInput), it's calling userNumeratorInput.toString()which   prints the properties of the text field, use ystem.out.println(userNumeratorInput.getText()) to print the text content of the field –  MadProgrammer*

Here is the correct code from my form class

```
package reducefraction;

import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    double userDenominator, userNumerator;

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {

        initComponents();
//        userDenominatorInput.addActionListener(new MyTextActionListener());
        userDenominatorInput.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MyDocumentListener());
        userDenominatorInput.getDocument().putProperty("name", "Text Field");

        /*    userDenominatorInput.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
         public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
         userDenominatorInputKeyReleased(evt);
         }
         });
         */
        //        userNumeratorInput.addActionListener(new MyTextActionListener());
        userNumeratorInput.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MyDocumentListener());
        userNumeratorInput.getDocument().putProperty("name", "Text Field");

        /*    
         userNumeratorInput.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
         public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
         userNumeratorInputKeyReleased(evt);
         }
         });
         */
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
        userDenominatorInput = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jSeparator2 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
        numeratorOutput = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        denominatorOutput = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        userNumeratorInput = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Reduce Fractions");

        jLabel2.setText("This program will reduce a fraction to its lowest terms");

        userDenominatorInput.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Gabriola", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        userDenominatorInput.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 51));

        numeratorOutput.setEditable(false);
        numeratorOutput.setColumns(10);
        numeratorOutput.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Gabriola", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        numeratorOutput.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 51));

        denominatorOutput.setEditable(false);
        denominatorOutput.setColumns(10);
        denominatorOutput.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Gabriola", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        denominatorOutput.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 51));

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tempus Sans ITC", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("=");

        userNumeratorInput.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Gabriola", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        userNumeratorInput.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 51));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(155, 155, 155)
                                .addComponent(jLabel1))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(75, 75, 75)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2)))
                        .addGap(0, 82, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jSeparator1)
                            .addComponent(userDenominatorInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 166, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(userNumeratorInput))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jSeparator2)
                            .addComponent(denominatorOutput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(numeratorOutput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 31, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(userNumeratorInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(userDenominatorInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jSeparator2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 14, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(denominatorOutput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(numeratorOutput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(50, 50, 50)))
                .addGap(22, 22, 22))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        
 /*   public void userDenominatorInputKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
     double userDenominator = Double.parseDouble(userDenominatorInput.getText());
     double userNumerator = Double.parseDouble(userNumeratorInput.getText());
     calculate(userNumerator, userDenominator);
     }
     */
    /*    public void userNumeratorInputKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
     double userDenominator = Double.parseDouble(userDenominatorInput.getText());
     double userNumerator = Double.parseDouble(userNumeratorInput.getText());
     calculate(userNumerator, userDenominator);
     }
     */

    public void update() {
        if (!userDenominatorInput.getText().isEmpty() && !userNumeratorInput.getText().isEmpty()) {
            double userDenominator = Double.parseDouble(userDenominatorInput.getText());
            double userNumerator = Double.parseDouble(userNumeratorInput.getText());
            calculate(userNumerator, userDenominator);
        }
    }

    public void calculate(double userNumerator, double userDenominator) {

        if (Double.toString(userNumerator).contains(".")) {
            int decimalLocationuserNumerator = Double.toString(userNumerator).lastIndexOf(".");
            String decimalsuserNumerator = Double.toString(userNumerator).substring(decimalLocationuserNumerator + 1, Double.toString(userNumerator).length());
            int magnitudeUserNumerator = decimalsuserNumerator.length();
            userNumerator = userNumerator * Math.pow(10, magnitudeUserNumerator);
            userDenominator = userDenominator * Math.pow(10, magnitudeUserNumerator);
        }

        if (Double.toString(userDenominator).contains(".")) {
            int decimalLocationUserDenominator = Double.toString(userDenominator).lastIndexOf(".");
            String decimalsUserDenominator = Double.toString(userDenominator).substring(decimalLocationUserDenominator + 1, Double.toString(userDenominator).length());
            int magnitudeUserDenominator = decimalsUserDenominator.length();
            userDenominator = userDenominator * Math.pow(10, magnitudeUserDenominator);
            userNumerator = userNumerator * Math.pow(10, magnitudeUserDenominator);
        }

        double a = userNumerator;
        double b = userDenominator;
        double c = a % b;

        while (c > 1) {
            c = a % b;
            a = b;
            b = c;
        }

        int greatestCommonDenominator = (int) a;

        int numeratorAnswer = (int) userNumerator / greatestCommonDenominator;
        int denominatorAnswer = (int) userDenominator / greatestCommonDenominator;

        numeratorOutput.setText(Integer.toString(numeratorAnswer));
        denominatorOutput.setText(Integer.toString(denominatorAnswer));

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField denominatorOutput;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField numeratorOutput;
    public javax.swing.JTextField userDenominatorInput;
    private javax.swing.JTextField userNumeratorInput;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    private class MyDocumentListener implements DocumentListener {

        public MyDocumentListener() {
        }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            update();

        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            update();

        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            update();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The "probable" cause is the use of `KeyListener` on the text fields.

The main problem is you are not taking into account what should occur if one of the fields is empty, "" is not a valid number.

Don't use `KeyListener`s on text fields, if you want to perform real time updates on fields, you should be using a `DocumentListener` instead.  `KeyListener` won't be notified if the the user pastes content into the field...

You should also consider using a `JSpinner` or a `JFormattedField` or even a `DocumentFilter` to restrict what the user can actually type into the fields

Something like...

```
if (!userDenominatorInput.getText().isEmpty() && !userNumeratorInput.getText().isEmpty()) {

    double userDenominator = Double.parseDouble(userDenominatorInput.getText());
    double userNumerator = Double.parseDouble(userNumeratorInput.getText());
    calculate(userNumerator, userDenominator);

}
```

Should help...

Comment: I implemented the document listener and I still received the same value of the textfield input that being the properties of the textfield

Comment: Don't use `System.out.println(userNumeratorInput)`, it's calling `userNumeratorInput.toString()` which prints the properties of the text field, use `ystem.out.println(userNumeratorInput.getText())` to print the text content of the field

Comment: Thanks so much, I think that was the main problem. I didn't getText to printout

Comment: For any others with a similar problem the main solution is GETTEXT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! before system out println